# QML: is it possible to change the long duration of a mouse Area

Tags: qt, qml

QML provides in its MouseArea component a PressAndHold signal, when a mouse area is pressed for a "long duration"
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#pressAndHold-signal

this duration is set to 800ms, and I find nowhere a way to modify this duration.
Can it be done and if so, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you will see the `MouseArea` source ([Src/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickmousearea.cpp](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/d43a963e49956ba772644e9f3448dc3672147f77:src/quick/items/qquickmousearea.cpp#L649)) you find this line:

```
d->pressAndHoldTimer.start(qApp->styleHints()->mousePressAndHoldInterval(), this);
```

The durations value came from `QStyleHints` but it's read-only since the value is platform specified. So the answer to your question: "No", if you are not going to change the source.

But you still can emulate this events, for example:

```
MouseArea {
    property int pressAndHoldDuration: 2000
    signal myPressAndHold()
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressed: {
        pressAndHoldTimer.start();
    }
    onReleased: {
        pressAndHoldTimer.stop();
    }
    onMyPressAndHold: {
        console.log("It works!");
    }

    Timer {
        id:  pressAndHoldTimer
        interval: parent.pressAndHoldDuration
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            parent.myPressAndHold();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify that by setting the `running` property of the `Timer` to `parent.pressed` and get rid of the `onPressed` and `onReleased` handlers.

Comment: The funny thing is, even by using private APIs, i.e. `QT += gui_private`, there is no direct `setMousePressAndHoldInterval` available (at least I didn't find it). I guess this property is "The Devil" :D

Comment: Is there a way to cancel onReleased event ? I've implemented a similar solution, but I would like to have myPressAndHold INSTEAD of the onReleased signa.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this can be directly configured with `setMousePressAndHoldInterval()` [(added in November 2015)](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/bc6af06b7db10bf797eb523e7cf78ca4c153b687), e.g.:

```
int pressAndHoldInterval = 2000; // in [ms]
QGuiApplication::styleHints()->setMousePressAndHoldInterval(pressAndHoldInterval);
```

Put the above at the beginning in your `main()`, along with

```
#include <QStyleHints>
```

and it will globally set the interval as desired.

**NOTE #1**: As per the [Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-24793?jql=text%20~%20%22pressandhold%22), this is a system-wide configuration, so individual MouseArea components cannot be fine-tuned.

**NOTE #2**: In [the source code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.7/src/gui/kernel/qstylehints.cpp#L147), the doxygen lists this as `\internal` so this might be removed/refactored without warning.

Answer (score 5):

Since Qt 5.9, the property `pressAndHoldInterval` overrides the elapsed time in milliseconds before `pressAndHold` is emitted.

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#pressAndHoldInterval-prop)

```
import QtQuick 2.9 // 2.9 or higher

MouseArea {
    pressAndHoldInterval: 100 // duration of 100ms
}
```